# http.server.requests and http.client.requests metrics not coming in spring actuator json

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

In my springboot application i can not see any http metrics.

I can only see below metrics:

```
    // 20230120164530
// http://localhost:8081/actuator/metrics

{
  "names": [
    "application.ready.time",
    "application.started.time",
    "disk.free",
    "disk.total",
    "executor.active",
    "executor.completed",
    "executor.pool.core",
    "executor.pool.max",
    "executor.pool.size",
    "executor.queue.remaining",
    "executor.queued",
    "jvm.buffer.count",
    "jvm.buffer.memory.used",
    "jvm.buffer.total.capacity",
    "jvm.classes.loaded",
    "jvm.classes.unloaded",
    "jvm.gc.live.data.size",
    "jvm.gc.max.data.size",
    "jvm.gc.memory.allocated",
    "jvm.gc.memory.promoted",
    "jvm.gc.overhead",
    "jvm.gc.pause",
    "jvm.memory.committed",
    "jvm.memory.max",
    "jvm.memory.usage.after.gc",
    "jvm.memory.used",
    "jvm.threads.daemon",
    "jvm.threads.live",
    "jvm.threads.peak",
    "jvm.threads.states",
    "logback.events",
    "process.cpu.usage",
    "process.files.max",
    "process.files.open",
    "process.start.time",
    "process.uptime",
    "resilience4j.retry.calls",
    "system.cpu.count",
    "system.cpu.usage",
    "system.load.average.1m",
    "tomcat.sessions.active.current",
    "tomcat.sessions.active.max",
    "tomcat.sessions.alive.max",
    "tomcat.sessions.created",
    "tomcat.sessions.expired",
    "tomcat.sessions.rejected"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the rest call to the api generated the http.server.requests and http.client.requests metrics